How to get an icon for the gnome dash from a terminal app that opens a window?
SWI-Prolog (https://www.swi-prolog.org) is primarily a terminal application, but it can open windows.  Compare to e.g., Python.   The graphics is using X11.  The free desktop standard says that the window icon is specified using the _NET_WM_ICON X property.
I know Gnome shell is application oriented and wants to find a .desktop file from the WM_CLASS attribute to decide on the icon to show.   That fits poorly with a terminal app that may open some window(s).
It is also mentioned that _NET_WM_ICON works as last resort and indeed, up to Fedora 39 using Gnome 45 this worked (tested on Asahi Fedora remix for Apple silicon).  However, on Fedora 40 (AMD64, Gnome 46), I just get a generic icon.
Is this a bug in Gnome 46?   Is there some other work-around?   It is rather involved to manage a desktop file for something this simple ...
